# Can I extend PostgreSQL (v10) tabelspace to multiple locations (file systems)?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

The file system where the tablespace resides on reaches it's max size.  I would like to extend the tablespace to another file system but I can't find any document to support that.  Can PostgreSQL (v10) tablespace use multiple locations (file systems)?

Comment: No, not possible. But on system level you can create or expand a volume group that spans multiple disks.